# Spring Boot 2 - disable Envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers

How can I disable `Hibernate Envers` in Spring Boot 2? I don't want to remove the dependency, because the code relies on it depending on the environment.

I tried the following properties in my `application.properties` but none worked. On startup it always prints `envers enabled = true`

```
spring.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try;

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```

"Non-Spring Data JPA" Hibernate properties are configured through `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.*` afaik. That might just do it!

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are two ways to disable hibernate envers in spring boot applications:

Wih **VM Arguments**:

```
-Dhibernate.integration.envers.enabled= false
```

With **hibernate.properties** (not application.properties) file, (if not exist, create) add the line below.

```
hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```