# How to disable envers auditing for spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate-envers, auditing

i am creating a maven multimoduled project one of the module for the hibernate entity only , issue is two services/api/maven_project are using same module , but one requires auditing but other dont , how i can keep my code intact (means ,without changing or removing @Audited annotation)  , how to enable or disable envers auditing at run time or compile time,
because after everything i have tried auditing is working for both api

i have tried

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false

hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false
hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false
```

Comment: can you exclude the Envers dependency for the module that doesn't require auditing? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: yes Jens but in order to do that  i have to change my all entity classes having @audited annotations and i want to keep them in order to use or enable them in future

Comment: If you set the dependencies to provided they will not be included in Spring Boot executable JAR and audting will not happen but the code compiles.

Comment: The module containing the entities will keep the dependency. The annotations being present in the byte code is not a problem because annotations in byte code not found in the classpath get ignored.

Comment: thanks Simon and Jens it worked fine but is there any other options for enabling or disabling auditing by application.properties because thing will get messy after a while when another child module/service is introduced like  A->B->C   where A is Entity Module B is service (with auditing enabled or disabled) and C is another Service with B as dependency (and C have the capability to enable or Disable auditing of B), just somehow want to keep configuration centralized

Answer (score 1):

As per [buræquete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3641067/bur%C3%A6quete)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337203/6279354)

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```

Would do the job.

> "Non-Spring Data JPA" Hibernate properties are configured through
>   `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.*`