# Disable Envers in properties file

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have already referred to this question: [Spring Boot 2 - disable Envers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337135/spring-boot-2-disable-envers), but the answer did not work for me.

I am using Spring Boot and would like to disable Envers in the properties file without having to go into my code and remove any @Audited annotations or such.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
hibernate.integration.envers.enable=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enable=false
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.integration.envers.enable=false
hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak specifically to the integration with Spring Boot, but you should be able to force it to be disabled by supplying a custom `hibernate.properties` file shown below:

```
# this disables hibernate envers, even if its on the classpath
hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```

Comment: Okay will test this. Thank you.